# When to use ROLLBACK, BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT

Tags: sql, database, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm not sure if im using rollback/commit properly; would someone be able to explain how to use them in python?

```
    PROCEDURE bookCar(  class IN INT,  from_date IN DATE,  to_date IN DATE, reservation_no OUT INT ) 
    DECLARE 
     available_car INT; 
    BEGIN 

    TRANSACTION

     SELECT car_id INTO  :available_car 
       FROM Cars 
      WHERE class= :class AND booked = FALSE 
      LIMIT 1; 

    COMMIT

     IF (  :available_car IS NOT NULL ) THEN BEGIN 

     TRANSACTION

         UPDATE Cars 
            SET booked = TRUE 
          WHERE car_id =  :available_car; 

--

         SELECT MAX(reservation_no)+1 INTO  :reservation_no 
           FROM Bookings; 
--         

         INSERT INTO Bookings VALUES( :reservation_no, :available_car, :from_date, :to_date ); 

    ROLLBACK

     ELSE 

    COMMIT

     END IF; 

    ROLLBACK

     END;
```

I would appreciate any help I could get as im really struggling with this! Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix your code formatting, thank you. Please see: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/296887)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?